# How can I check if two lists are equal to one another on python

Tags: python, list

I'm developing a code breaker game where the user is given a coded list and the user has to guess what letter each symbol represents. When the user thinks he has replaced all of the symbols with the correct letters he/she would then type 'check'. 
What I want my check function to do, is to compare the users list with a separate list with the correct answers but I am stuck on how to do so.

Comment: Um... have you tried the equality operator? `list1 == list2`

Comment: No I'm quite new to python what exactly does it do and how would I use it

Comment: This is not a python specific feature - it is a general programming operator that should exist in most (if not all) languages. Perhaps you should go back and run through some python tutorials to get a better foundation.

Comment: There is absolutely no way you'll be able to get anywhere near a working game without understanding basic comparison operators.

Comment: A problem here is that obviously your user will enter their attempt at the code using `input()` or `raw_input()` this returns a `string` and not a `list` so if you did `list1 == users_list` it wouldn't work as one is a list, one is a string. You could get around this by getting the user to enter their numbers 1 by 1 and `append`ing them to their list, or you could get a bit more clever with it.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the `==` operator, it calls the method `__eq__` on the list which check the elements equality:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a == c
False
```

Comment: Note that if `d = [3, 2, 1]` then `a == d` will be False.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, those are different lists, they are equals sets.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I meant to direct that previous comment to the OP.

Comment: @PM2Ring No problem at all ;)